# What's AuthorizationLevel.User and how to use it correctly?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I just configured my function app to use azure active directory. After that I wanted to deactivated the function level authentication by changing the enum at the HttpTrigger Attribute. Then I discovered that there is the possibility to switch to "User" AuthorizationLevel which is described as:

> Allow access to requests that include a valid authentication token

After I deployed my Function I only get 401 unauthorized requests, so i switched back to Anonymous authorization level.

```
public enum AuthorizationLevel
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Allow access to anonymous requests.
        Anonymous = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Allow access to requests that include a valid authentication token
        User = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Allow access to requests that include a function key
        Function = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Allows access to requests that include a system key
        System = 3,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Allow access to requests that include the master key
        Admin = 4
    }
```

So my question is, how to use "user" authorization level correctly? And can I use it with azure active directory enabled?

Comment: Just posted this issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/114479  Feel free to back it up ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`User` isn't currently supported. It will eventually be used to support App Service authentication, but that doesn't work today.

Comment: Having the same issue! Is it still not supported?

Answer (score 2):

As of today user level is still unsupported, its scheduled for:

> v2 GA release (which also doesn't have a specific date, other than
>   later this year).

Progress can be tracked here; [Support EasyAuth #33](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/33).

Answer (score 2):

It's supported now. You can check the discussion here: [issue-auth](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/33)

Comment: though easy auth is working, AuthorizationLevel.User still seems to not be a supported option

Comment: I have gotten confirmation from the product team that in fact it _is_ not yet supported. Even in V3.